# How Can I Encode My New Xml Document?

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, xmldocument

I have a string with a XML text and i want to save it like XML. I encoded string (to "utf-8") but when i want to make XML from that - my cyrillic symbols in Value don't displayed right . What i need to do to encode my XML document ?

part of my xml :

```
 <rev:Code>Мои данные</rev:Code>
```

my code:

```
 string send = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf8").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetBytes(send)); 
XmlDocument docsec = new XmlDocument();
 docsec.LoadXml(send);
docsec.Save("C:\\XmlNEW.xml");
```

Original text :Мои данные

I see it after creating XML :РњРѕРё РґР°РЅРЅС‹Рµ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Save Method because it use xml encoding, i take my answer from this : [Answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/895637/How-Can-I-Encode-My-New-Xml-Document)

```
XmlDocument docsec = new XmlDocument();
docsec.LoadXml(send);
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\XmlNEW.xml", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    docsec.Save(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked with russian textfiles before to convert them to rtf and used "Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)" for that purpose.